# Copying a matrix into another matrix ocaml

Tags: matrix, ocaml, setvalue

I am trying to copy a the values of the first matrix to the second element by element. I don't understand why "<-" doesn't work for me when I want to set a new value. Here's the code:

```
let y=[|[|"true";"true";"false";"false"|];
        [|"true";"false";"true";"false"|];
        [|"false";"false";"true";"true"|];
        [|"false";"true";"false";"true"|]|]
;;

let fill_array = 
  let l=Array.length x in
  for i=0 to l-1 do
    for j=0 to l-1 do
      x.(i).(j)<-(y(i).(j))
    done;
  done;
  x;;
```

I get the following-Error: This expression has type string array array
This is not a function; it cannot be applied.
Ideally this would be a bool array but I wanted to try string first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a dot. In

```
x.(i).(j)<- y(i).(j)
```

`y(i)` is a function application whereas you wanted `y.(i)`

```
x.(i).(j)<- y.(i).(j)
```

Note that for an element-by-element copy, another option would be to use higher-order functions rather than low-level loops:

```
let copy x y =
  Array.iteri (fun i xi ->
    Array.iteri (fun j x -> y.(i).(j) <- x) xi
  ) x
```

Answer (score 2):

In OCaml parlance, to copy means to create a copy of something. And for the process of filling the contents of one data structure with another, we use the word `blit`. It is rather OCaml-specific, and probably confusing but it is good to know as it will help you navigate the OCaml documentation. It is always good to know what is the name of a thing that you search :)

### Copying

To copy a matrix just do `Array.(map copy)`, e.g.,

```
let xs = Array.make 10 10 0 
let ys = Array.(map copy) xs
let () = 
  ys.(0).(0) <- 1;
  assert (xs.(0).(0) = 0)
```

Here, `Array.(map copy)` is using the local open feature of OCaml and is the same as `Array.map Array.copy`. The `Array.map` function creates a new array that faps each element of the original array using the provided function, in our case it is `Array.copy`. To copy a 3d matrix you can do `Array.(map@@map copy)` and so on.

### Blitting

If you want to copy your matrix into an existing matrix then the most efficient way would be to use `Array.blit`, e.g.,

```
let blit_matrix ~dst ~src = 
  Array.iteri (fun row dst ->
    Array.blit src.(row) 0 dst 0 (Array.length src.(row))) dst
```