# "Lights out" game in Ocaml, arrays and exception handling

Tags: arrays, function, exception, ocaml, indexoutofboundsexception

The exercise is given like this:

> 1. Create a function flip
>    val flip : bool array array -> int -> int -> bool array array = 
>    that given a bool matrix and two integers i, j. it negates the values
>    (true→false, false→true) at location i, j in the matrix, as well negating
>    the values on the (up to) 4 horizontally/vertically adjacent elements.

Here is my function:

```
let flip m a b=
for i=0 to ((Array.length m)-1) do 
    for j=0 to ((Array.length m.(1))-1) do
        if i=a && j=b then
        begin 
        m.(i).(j) <- not m.(i).(j);
        try m.(i-1).(j) <- not m.(i-1).(j) with (Invalid_argument "index out of bounds") -> ();
        try m.(i).(j-1) <- not m.(i).(j-1) with (Invalid_argument "index out of bounds") -> ();
        try m.(i+1).(j) <- not m.(i+1).(j) with (Invalid_argument "index out of bounds") -> ();
        try m.(i).(j+1) <- not m.(i).(j+1) with (Invalid_argument "index out of bounds") -> ();
        end;
    done;
done;
m;;
```

When I feed this function any kind of 2d bool array I get back the same array with no changes to it. What am I doing wrong I don't see it?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the inputs you're providing to this function?

Comment: @ChrisDutton yes, I declare a 3 by 4 matrix like this:  `let matrix =[|[|false; true; true; false|]; [|true; false; false; true|]; [|false; false; true; true|]|];;` and then I run it by my function like this `flip matrix 1 4;;` and I get back the same matrix with no changes to it.

```- : bool array array =
[|[|false; true; true; false|]; [|true; false; false; true|];
  [|false; false; true; true|]|]
```

Comment: Tip: If you edit your question, you can format these things more nicely.

Comment: You should try thoroughly testing your code by trying other inputs to `flip`. Consider looking for 1 and 4. Arrays in OCaml are indexed from 0, so the upper bound of your 4 element arrays will never be greater than 3, but your conditional ends up checking for equality to 4. Why should you expect anything to ever happen?

Comment: @ChrisDutton ah yes I see, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing wrong is left out of your question as your function, while not perfect, at least mutates the input array and returns it, e.g.,

```
# let x = Array.create_matrix 3 3 true;;
val x : bool array array =
  [|[|true; true; true|]; [|true; true; true|]; [|true; true; true|]|]
# flip x 1 1;;
- : bool array array =
[|[|true; false; true|]; [|true; false; true|]; [|true; true; true|]|]
```

So, as you can see, some values are flipped. As we can see from the comments section, you create a matrix of 3x4 (with 3 rows and 4 columns) and then ask to change an element with index (1,4) that corresponds to the second row and fith column, as arrays are indexed in OCaml (as well as many other programming languages from zero). Since `j` is always less than 4 (it ranges from `0` to `Array.length(1) - 1` per your code, which is 0,1,2,3` the condition never happens. But again this is not the problem with your function, but with the invocation of your function.

There are some issues with your function though.

1. it is not making a copy of the input array but mutates it in place see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67418891/copying-a-matrix-into-another-matrix-ocaml) for more information
2. you're catching exceptions while it would be better to use a loop to negate "the (up to) 4 horizontally/vertically adjacent elements". Your approach might work, but it doesn't scale and definitely will not be graded well (hint, this is not what your teachers expect you to do). Also, in the current implementation it mutates only up to 1 row and column, so to make your approach work correctly you need three times more lines of code. You can try writing them though as it might help you seeing the pattern and turning it into an iteration.
3. when you catch exceptions never match on the error message, it makes your code brittle as it depends on the actual contents (and language) of the error message. You can write
   `try m.(i-1).(j) <- not m.(i-1).(j) with _ -> ()`, at least it is less verbose and it will be easier to see the missing pattern.
4. `for j=0 to ((Array.length m.(1))-1) do` you're taking the second row of your matrix as the dimension. It won't work if your matrix has only one row, and in general for array of arrays that are not matrices, i.e., that have a different number of elements in each row. It is better and more robust to do `for j=0 to Array.length m.(i) - 1 do`, e.g., to use the length of the current, `i`-th, row.

Comment: Given the issues identified in the comments on the question, I suspect some of the problem may lie with a general misunderstanding of OCaml array indexing starting at `0`, rather than `1`.

Comment: Yep, you're right, let me update the posting.

Comment: @ivg Thank you! I followed all your (4) advices and now my code works hahaha. When I look at my code for this long of a time the obvious things just fly over my head. Kudos!

Comment: _Everything_ seems obvious in hindsight.

Comment: You're welcome) And yeah, it will always happen to you and happens to me and any other programmer. You start with a program that is absolutely correct to your understanding and you have no idea why it is not working, you starting to judge the compiler and world constants, until a couple of minutes/hours/days later, you finally got it and now you can't really understand how didn't you get it before. Everything was so obvious... in hindsight)) To  be honest, I like this effect. I keep coding for this "ahha!" effects, when chaos turns into order, well until the next time it disorders again))